# Best suitable JVM implementation for Realtime Applications of Telecom domain

Tags: java, jvm

Out of many implementations of JVM, which is most suitable for Realtime Applications like applications for Telecom domain?

I am working on an application of Telecom domain, and wanted some advice regarding the choice of JVM.

Currently using HotSpot but read somewhere regarding JRockit and Azul.

If some one uses one of these JVMs and has seen some major improvements in performance please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HostSpot JVM is pretty good and cost-effectve option. It provides few GC algorithms, in particular Concurrent Mark Sweep is good for certain kinds of real-time applications.
G1 is another low-pause GC algorithm, which is actively promoted by Oracle, but so far its results are quite disappointing.

JRockit - is deadend. It never had good low-pause GC algorithm and it is going to be merged in to HotSpot.

Azul Zing - is another league compared to HotSpot/JRockit.It really reliably keep GC pauses in order of milliseconds, but it requires more complex setup. It has few deployment options (virtual appliance, etc) you should check whenever it would fit your infrastructure.

On general note

No JVM could **guaranty** you minimal GC pause time, it is always **best effort**. There are lot of factors affecting GC puases duration and most of them very application specific.

If your are seeking **guarantied** response time below 5ms (not just for 99.9...% responses but for 100%), you should consider techniques avoid Java heap memory usage (i.e. using off-heap memory or static memory preallocation).

Here few links where you can find more specific details about GC algorithms and low-pause tuning.

- [Understanding GC pauses in JVM, HotSpot's minor GC](http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/06/understanding-gc-pauses-in-jvm-hotspots.html)
- [Understanding GC pauses in JVM, HotSpot's CMS collector](http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/06/understanding-gc-pauses-in-jvm-hotspots_02.html)
- [JRockit GC in action](http://java.dzone.com/)
- [GC checklist for data grid nodes](http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/07/gc-check-list-for-data-grid-nodes.html)

Comment: It's true that no JVM is slow but performance depends on our Heap allocation and GC strategy. Also I wanted to know if somebody has seen some other useful features in other JVMs like Azul one